# StructureMap: How to replace object at runtime

Tags: structuremap

I am trying to inject mocked instance of ISession (NHibernate) to structure map. Currently it all wires it up in a Bootstrap method, but I want to replace the one that is injected with a mocked one. I tried EjectAllInstancesOf but it throw execption.

```
 [TestFixtureSetUp]
        public void TestFixtureSetup()
        {
            Bootstrapper.Bootstrap();
           //TODO: need to remove already wired up types that we are mocking.
            var mockSession = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ISession>();
            var mockLoggerFactory = MockRepository.GenerateStub<ILoggerFactory>();

            ObjectFactory.EjectAllInstancesOf<ISession>();
            ObjectFactory.EjectAllInstancesOf<ILoggerFactory>();

            ObjectFactory.Inject<ISession>(mockSession);
            ObjectFactory.Inject<ILoggerFactory>(mockLoggerFactory);
        }
```

Error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object. at
>   StructureMap.Pipeline.HttpContextLifecycle.findHttpDictionary() in
>   c:\dev\opensource\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\HttpContextLifecycle.cs:
>   line 50 at StructureMap.Pipeline.HttpContextLifecycle.FindCache() in
>   c:\dev\opensource\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\HttpContextLifecycle.cs:
>   line 28 at StructureMap.Pipeline.HttpContextLifecycle.EjectAll() in
>   c:\dev\opensource\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\HttpContextLifecycle.cs:
>   line 23 at StructureMap.Pipeline.HttpLifecycleBase`2.EjectAll() in
>   c:\dev\opensource\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Pipeline\HttpLifecycleBase.cs:
>   line 18 at StructureMap.InstanceFactory.EjectAllInstances() in
>   c:\dev\opensource\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\InstanceFactory.cs:
>   line 127 at StructureMap.PipelineGraph.EjectAllInstancesOf() in
>   c:\dev\opensource\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\PipelineGraph.cs:
>   line 193 at StructureMap.Container.EjectAllInstancesOf() in
>   c:\dev\opensource\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\Container.cs: line
>   393 at StructureMap.ObjectFactory.EjectAllInstancesOf() in
>   c:\dev\opensource\structuremap\Source\StructureMap\ObjectFactory.cs:
>   line 277

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this exception because your plugin type (ISession) is set up in StructureMap as a HttpContext lifecycle, and there is no HttpContext in a unit test.  This is probably a bug in StructureMap, it should probably throw it's own exception explaining the problem instead of hitting a NullReferenceException.

at any rate, in your unit test setup (Boostrapper), change the lifecycle of ISession to Hybrid or something besides HttpContext.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the calls to `EjectAllInstancesOf()`. Calling `Inject()` should do what you want.

Comment: It does not, it actually has two instances, one that  was auto-wired and one that is mock. It seems to be the issue only with ISession and the way it is wired up, because I can eject all other types. I ended up ejecting all repositories and replacing them with mocks. See update